# Bashrc- export path, not a valid identifier

Tags: bash

I am quite new to various shell operations.

I am trying to set my enviroment to be able to work with nvidia compilator (nvcc). 
I tried to modify my bashrc file as below answer says:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvcc-no-command-nvcc-found/14543/4

But when i run modified bashrc file following error occurs:

```
/c/Users/micha/.bashrc: line 1: export: `Files/NVIDIA': not a valid identifier                                          /c/Users/micha/.bashrc: line 1: export: `Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/lib:': not a valid identifier                               
/c/Users/micha/.bashrc: line 2: export: `Files/NVIDIA': not a valid identifier                                          /c/Users/micha/.bashrc: line 2: export: `Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/bin:/c/Users/micha/Anaconda3/envs/mpr:
/c/Users/micha/Anaconda3/envs/mpr/Library/mingw-w64/bin:/c/Users/micha/Anaconda3/envs/mpr/Library
/usr/bin:/c/Users/micha/Anaconda3/envs/mpr/Library/bin:/c/Users/micha/Anaconda3/envs/mpr/Scripts:
/c/Users/micha/Anaconda3/envs/mpr/bin:/c/Users/micha/Anaconda3/Scripts/condabin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local
/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32
/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl': not a valid identifier
```

My current bashrc code is:

```
# Different platforms have different names for the systemwide bashrc
if [[ -f /etc/bashrc ]]; then
  source /etc/bashrc
fi
if [[ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]]; then
  source /etc/bash.bashrc
fi
if [[ -f ~/.bashrc ]]; then
  source ~/.bashrc
fi

# Reset PS1 so pexpect can find it
PS1="$"

# Unset PROMPT_COMMAND, so that it can't change PS1 to something unexpected.
unset PROMPT_COMMAND

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/lib"
export PATH="C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/bin"
```

My path to nvcc is C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2\bin -as i think the spaces might cause some problems.
I am using Windows10 and I am trying to setup my Anaconda environment to work with pyCUDA.

Do you have any ideas why solution from question doesn't work for me? How could i fix it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry... I updated the post now.

Comment: `PATH="C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2/bin"` I strongly do not believe you want only a single path in your `PATH`. Please check your file for dos line endings.